# How to Close JQuery Messi Popup Box

Tags: jquery

I read all site contents, examples but couldn't find a command to manually close Messi pop up window. I know there is a close button in the title. but I want place a custom close button and automatically close the popup after completing xhr.

Messi project page: http://sri.im/messi

Here is my javascript for automatically close the popup after completing xhr

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#update").click(function() {

        $.post("./Index/StatusUpdateDo",

        {status: $("#status").val()},

        function(data, status) {

            $('#update').hide('slow');

            $('#done').show('slow');

            //SELF CLOSE COMMAND GOES HERE

        });

    });

});
```

NB. I'm a beginner to JQuery.

Comment: `autoclose Close message after 'x' milliseconds. null`

Comment: @steo we only can call autoclose when onclick popup link. is it? can we call it after it pop up? also i want to close it manually. not after some period.

Comment: edited my answer, check it out

Comment: @steo that's why i put that as example. please check my codes. i want to self close after xhr complete. but at that time popup already exists.

Comment: what's the code of your messi modal?

Comment: @steo <a href="#" onclick="javascript:Messi.load('./Index/Status_Update', {title: 'Status Update'});">Status Update</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. Using following line/function we can close the Messi popup manually.

```
$('.messi').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the modal option of the plugin you should also remove it. This will do the trick.

```
 $('.messi,.messi-modal').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can close it just with the `click()` method:

```
$('.messi .messi-closebtn').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should close the Modal after 2000ms

```
new Messi('This is a message with Messi.', {title: 'Title', autoclose: 2000});
```

**edit**

according to the DOC

```
closeButton Show close button in header title (or content if buttons array is empty).   tru
```

so

```
new Messi('This is a message with Messi.', {title: 'Title',closeButton: true});
```

should show a `close` `button` in the header.

First of all , `bind` the anchor inside your `script.js`, so change to:

```
 <a href="#" id="yourid">Status Update</a>
```

Then in jQuery script:

```
 $('#yourid').on('click', function() {
   Messi.load('./Index/Status_Update', {title: 'Status Update' , closeButton: true });
 });
```

of course instead of `yourid` you can use whatewever `id` name you want